# Deploy Apache Archiva on tomcat 6

Tags: deployment, tomcat6, archiva

I am trying to deploy Apache Archiva on my Server, but it just fails all the time.

specs:

```
os: ubuntu 10.04 
tomcat: Apache Tomcat/6.0.24
jvm: 1.6.0_27-b27

$CATALINA_HOME : /usr/share/tomcat6
$CATALINA_BASE : /var/lib/tomcat6
$CATALINA_OPTS : "-Dappserver.home=$CATALINA_HOME -Dappserver.base=$CATALINA_BASE"

path to lib : $CATALINA_BASE/common/lib

#java -version
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.3) (6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~10.04.1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Tomcat itself is up and running. I followed the instructions on this [page](https://cwiki.apache.org/ARCHIVA/archiva-on-tomcat.html), copied all the necessary jars to the lib (location specified above), created the `archiva.xml` in `/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/Catalina/localhost/` with that content:

```
<Context path="/archiva" docBase="/var/lib/tomcat6/archiva/apache-archiva-1.4-M4.war">

  <Resource name="jdbc/users"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="philipp"
        password="xxx"
        driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"
        url="jdbc:derby:////localhost:1527/archivausers;create=true" />

  <Resource name="jdbc/archiva"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="philipp"
        password="xxx"
        driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"
        url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/archivadata;create=true" />

  <Resource name="mail/Session"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.mail.Session"
        mail.smtp.host="localhost"/>
</Context>
```

After a click on »start« in the tomcat manager: `FAIL - Application at context path /archiva could not be started`

the last lines on the `catalina.out` are:

`SCHWERWIEGEND: A web application created a ThreadLocal with key of type[java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@69bf9]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent] (value [Logger=org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader Level=ERROR Message=Context initialization failed]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the ThreadLocal has been forcibly removed.
11.06.2013 16:29:30 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SCHWERWIEGEND: A web application created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.DefaultThreadContextMap$1@1ea380c]) and a value of type [null] (value [null]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the ThreadLocal has been forcibly removed.`

I tried more or less everything what came to my mind, but always FAIL!

Any Idea?

Comment: more lines from the logs are needed to identify the issue.

Comment: I could manage to make it running. There were serveral issues I had to deal with and right now I am about to write an answer that explains. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I could manage to get it running I think it could be useful for somebody else to share the steps I have taken. These descriptions assume that one has already has read the official [installation Instructions](https://cwiki.apache.org/ARCHIVA/archiva-on-tomcat.html) of archiva and should be a kind of additional explanation due to the fact that the official documentation could be a bit more verbose.

First I downloaded the »war« and stored it in `/var/lib/tomcat6/archiva`, this defines the starting point.

**1. Database:**

In the official [instruction](https://cwiki.apache.org/ARCHIVA/archiva-on-tomcat.html) one is asked to download `derby.jar` and `derbytools.jar` to save them in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` (in my case that points to `/usr/share/tomcat6/lib`) to make the files available for all web application running on this tomcat. On my research I came over the [apache derby project](http://db.apache.org/derby/) where I also found this command:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-javadb-core sun-javadb-client
```

which just installs the derby db (in my case I had to add »multiverse« in `/etc/apt/sources.list` at the of one source). After that I run:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/javadb/lib/*.jar -t /usr/share/tomcat6/lib
```

what linked all needed derby-jars to the tomcat lib (probably some are not needed there). After that I created the directory `db` in `/var/lib/tomcat6/archiva` and changed its owner and group to tomcat6, but it is up to you where you want to store the database files, but it is important *not to create the two subdirectories* for the two needed databases, namly: `users` and `archiva`, inside that directory.

**2. Mail**

There I followed the Instructions and copied `mail.jar` and `activation.jar` to tomcats library.

**3. archiva home directory**

One of the Errors that prevented archiva from running was that it tried to create a home Directory in `/usr/share/tomcat6/.m2`, but that resulted in an permission conflict, so I created that directory and changed group and owner to tomcat6.

**Last but not least** I cared about the `archiva.xml`, located in in `/var/lib/conf/Catalina/localhost`. Since the paths that should be replaced were not marked in »bold« it is kind of easy to oversee them, so I try to do that here, using `${path}` to point that out:

```
<Context path="/archiva"
     docBase="${path to the archiva war archive here}">

  <Resource name="jdbc/users"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="sa"
        password=""
        driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"
        url="jdbc:derby:${path to the db folder}/users;create=true" />

  <Resource name="jdbc/archiva"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="sa"
        password=""
        driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"
        url="jdbc:derby:${path to db folder}/archiva;create=true" />

  <Resource name="mail/Session"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.mail.Session"
        mail.smtp.host="localhost"/>
</Context>
```

That should be everything and I hope that I did not forgot anything to mention. Searching the `catalina.out` for error logs is a kind of senseless since the messages in there do not describe explicit problems, therefor I want to suggest to read `localhost.${date}.log` in the same directory, therein I could find debug information which was much more useful.

p.s.: After the Installation of Archiva did the very same Steps for Apache Continuum, just replacing folder- and filenames, what resulted in a running Installation, too.

Happy Install, cheers!

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks!  In my case I also needed to make and chown directories /var/lib/tomcat6/data and /var/lib/tomcat6/repositories.  This is on ubuntu-14.04 with archiva-2.2.1.