# Apache Continuum—deploying on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, deployment, continuum

I have deployed Apache continuum on my tomcat in the same way I installed archiva ([detailed description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046850/deploy-apache-archiva-on-tomcat-6/)). The webapp is running but there is an issue I do not come over:

When I restart tomcat the configuration is gone. By searching the log files I could find that error in `continuum.log`:

```
2013-09-29 17:49:57,043 [main] WARN org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder  - Internal error
org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: Cannot locate configuration source /var/lib/tomcat6/conf/shared.xml
```

Any Idea how to fix that?

**EDIT**

Digging deeper in the log file I found a preceding error:

```
2013-09-29 18:01:58,246 [Thread-3] INFO  org.apache.maven.continuum.DefaultContinuum  - Error storing the Continuum configuration.
org.apache.continuum.configuration.ContinuumConfigurationException: /var/lib/tomcat6/conf/continuum.xml (Permission denied)
```

Here continuum is looking for the default configuration, but this one is located somewhere in `webapps/continuum/…`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `appserver.base` being set, as the other question suggests, to the correct location? It seems like that is pointint to `/var/lib/tomcat6`, but that the directory is not writeable by the user that is running the Tomcat instance.

Comment: the changing the permissions did the trick. Is there a way to tell continuum where to store the configuration?

Comment: The `appserver.base` configuration specified in the description you gave is the location it will use - but if not specified it'll default to the Tomcat home. More information here: http://continuum.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/installation/tomcat.html#Configure_the_appserver.base_Java_system_property

Answer (score 0):

That's an [info] message, not an error. The tomcat service would still function even if you ignore that. However, please check the file/directory permissions to correct that. If you are running tomcat with normal user privileges, they wouldn't have access to /var/lib/tomcat6/ directory.